# Dynamically generating checkboxes from ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to generate checkboxes with ng-repeat.After selecting a value from dropdown I am getting values based on value selected.But after I select any checkbox only first checkbox is getting checked.I am not able to select other checkboxes.Can anyone tell how to select any one checkbox or more than one so that I can bind that values based on ng-model.

Here is the html code

```
    <div class="form-group" data-ng-repeat="collegesByType in 
    collegesByTypes">
    <div class="be-checkbox">
    <input data-ng-model="committee.collegeId" name="collegeId"
    type="hidden"
    value="0">
    <input data-to-date="currently_todate386" 
    id="currently_checkbox386" class="currently" type="checkbox" 
    value="1">
    <label for="currently_checkbox386">{{collegesByType.name}}</label>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: You should define separate model for each check box. such as this `data-ng-model="collegesByType .committee.collegeId"`

Answer (score 0):

Try Like this:

```
<div class="form-group" data-ng-repeat="collegesByType in 
    collegesByTypes track by $index">
    <div class="be-checkbox">
    <input data-ng-model="committee.collegeId[collegesByType.collegeId]" name="collegeId"
    type="hidden"
    ng-value="collegesByType.collegeId">
    <input data-to-date="currently_todate386" 
    id="currently_checkbox386{{$index}}" class="currently" type="checkbox" 
    value="1">
    <label for="currently_checkbox386{{$index}}">{{collegesByType.name}}</label>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yea now i am able to select individual checkboxes.Thank you.Can I get the values of selected checkboxes for saving through data-ng-model="committee.collegeId[$index]"?

Comment: you will get all selected checkbox  inside $scope.committee.collegeId object

Comment: Its because I am passing only committee object to backened for saving as it has other fields.I am binding other fields with committee object and collegeId is one of the field

Comment: whats is the structure of collegesByType ?

Comment: After selecting college Type from dropdown I am getting all colleges based on college Type selected.Now i am getting colleges and also checkboxes alongside.After selecting colleges from checkbox I need to save.For that i am using committee object.Here is the structure of collegesByTypes                                 $scope.getAllCollegesByType = function(collegeTypeId){
AdminCollegeService.getAllCollegesByType(collegeTypeId).then(function(response){
   $scope.collegesByTypes=response.data;
  });
  }

Comment: bro i was like what is the structure of collegesByTypes like does it have college id or something else which you need to save in database!

Comment: It has List of Colleges.private List<College> colleges;

Comment: i am asking do a console.log(collegesByTypes) and share the results

Comment: It returned object.Object has these properties:collegeId: 4,collegeTypeId: 3,collegename: "College of Degree"

Comment: After i click submit It is showing 400 bad request in console.Can you please help.

Comment: I have posted my entire question with all the details.The question is "Saving of Checkboxes selected into database using Angular and spring mvc".I have not asked many questions so you can find it easily.If you have time please go through.Any help will be greatly appreciated.Thank you